# Display Image based on cell criteria

Tags: c#

Using Visual Studio 2015 and C# here. I have a DataGridView based on one of my SQL tables. I have added in a DataGridViewImageColumn which is blank at the minute.

I need to somehow display an image in this cell based on the criteria which is ;

IF cell = Y then display image, if blank show nothing. I am relatively new to C# still if anybody could point me in the right direction that would be really helpful.

I'm not asking for somebody to write code for me, just if there is a function to go by that will help I can then look in to.

And YES I have of course googled it many times and tried various bits of code amending to fit my criteria / solution, I cannot get any of them to work.

Comment: Code for what you have tried is suggested, then we can pick out the problem areas.  Otherwise all we can do is give the same as what you've already found.

Comment: You may want bind it to a property of your item in the datasource, Which property can be of Image type and prensent the right image upon your condition

Comment: How you store image in database: image path or blob?